# Dynamic Routes w/ validate in definePageMeta in Nuxt.js 3

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Here is the demo for my issue: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tvfhua?file=pages%2F[...category].vue,pages%2F[...article_slug].vue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tvfhua?file=pages%2F%5B...category%5D.vue,pages%2F%5B...article_slug%5D.vue)

My case is when user accessing to path of category can be nested ***(category-1/category-2)*** it will fetch all articles of the final category ***(category-2)*** then when user access to an article the path will be **/category-1/category-2/article-slug.html** then it will fetch the detail of the article but based on that article slug.

I tried with "validate" in definePageMeta but seemingly it is not working